# Meaning of "bearing"

Tags: prepositions, meaning-in-context

> Knowledge having a **bearing** on human life was placed highest
>
> Knowledge **about** human life was placed highest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bearing):

> **bearing** (*n.*, pl. *bearings*)
>   1. A mechanical device that supports another part and/or reduces friction.
>   2. (nautical) The horizontal angle between the direction of an object and that of true north; >subject to variation and deviation when taken by a magnetic compass
>   **3. Relevance; a relationship or connection.** "*That has no bearing on this issue.*"
>   4. One's posture, demeanor, or manner.

So, in your sentence, *bearing* uses the third definition that is given, which I rewrite as "to have a relationship or a relevance with."  That is, your sentence might be rephrased as the following: "Knowledge that has to do with, or has a connection with, human life was placed highest."

Comment: How about 'about'?

Comment: @user5015 Yes, _about_ would be a fair synonym for _bearing_ here.

Comment: Why not use 'about'? It's simple and easy to understand. Is there any difference?

Comment: @user5015 The difference between using _bearing_ and _about_ here is kind of subtle.  If you said, "knowledge about", there is an implication that this kind of knowledge could _only_ be applied to questions on human life; _about_ is much more direct.   In contrast, saying, "knowledge bearing", would have the connotation that one might use that knowledge for other questions; that that knowledge might apply to other domains as well, say questions about animal life. _About_  sounds more awkward than _bearing_ because it less descriptive, indeed almost too basic for adult speech.

Comment: @user5015 You should also note that whenever _bearing_ is used in this "relevance" sense, it always takes the preposition _on_. It is easy to recognize that way.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of *bearing on* is "relation or relevance" (*bearing* is a noun).
The meaning of *about* is (among others) "on the subject of; concerning."

The difference between the two sentences is that in the first the knowledge is related to human life, while in the second the knowledge topic is human life.

*Bearing on* is usually used in sentences such as "the case has no direct bearing on the issues."

If I should choose between the two sentences, I would choose the second one. Alternatively, I would rephrase the sentence, but I don't see any reason to not use *about*.